# Nodal Analysis Q

Tags: nodal-analysis

[image]

Hello, I'm studying Electrical Engineering, but I'm confused about nodal analysis. How to find  all nodal voltages and the current through the 4 Ω resistore?Please someone help me to understand this question.

Comment: There are several questions about nodal anaysis on Stack Exchange. that will show you the method. Show us your work and tell us *in your question* where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a **hint**: -

[image]

If you still can't solve it then I think you need to read your text books on source transformation and Thevenin's theorem. But, if you do manage to solve this and, you want to check you have the right answers, use a simulator: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I try to solve this question by using hint that you gave. Can you verify? First equation: V2-V1/10 + V2-V3/20 = 2  Second equation: V3-V2/20 + V3-V1/5 + V3-0/4 =0. Solve this system I got V2=17.9V, V3=3.8V and V1=5V am i wrong?

Comment: @PaulC That looks correct <-- I added a simulation into my answer so I could check. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: I appreciate it! It helps me well!